# I'm constantly getting a 403 when loading the css dynamically, what could be the cause?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On [this site](http://siliconbeachla.com/events-2/calendar/) I can't load the CSS because I'm constantly getting a 403 for my CSS which is loaded from this address: http://siliconbeachla.com/?ai1ec_render_css=1358530067&ver=3.5

There must be some rewrite rule which is blocking that, this is the part of their .htaccess file which is probably responsible for that (I'm no Apache expert).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN Better WP Security
# Begin HackRepair.com Blacklist
RewriteEngine On
#Block comment spammers, bad bots and some proxies
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 12.226.240.248 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 24.111.102.26 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 24.117.121.113 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 65.30.216.140 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 67.87.64.23 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 68.12.149.198 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 69.139.167.203 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 74.95.182.57 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 91.121.3.29 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 203.94.229.227 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 208.96.122.142 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 210.0.141.247 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 210.197.97.67 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 212.179.127.188 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 216.246.60.183 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 220.156.189.233 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 222.36.12.42 [OR]
# Abuse Agent Blocking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bolt\ 0 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot\@yahoo\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} CazoodleBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Default\ Browser\ 0 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DIIbot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} discobot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ecxi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailCollector [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} GT::WWW [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} heritrix [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTP::Lite [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ia_archiver [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} IDBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} id-search [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} id-search\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InternetSeer\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} IRLbot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ISC\ Systems\ iRc\ Search\ 2\.1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Java [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Link [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} LinksManager.com_bot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} linkwalker [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} lwp-trivial [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Maxthon$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MFC_Tear_Sample [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^microsoft\.url [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Microsoft\ URL\ Control [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Missigua\ Locator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla\.*Indy [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla\.*NEWT [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MSFrontPage [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Nutch [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} panscient.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PECL::HTTP [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PeoplePal [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PHPCrawl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PleaseCrawl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^psbot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Rippers\ 0 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} SBIder [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SeaMonkey$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^sitecheck\.internetseer\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Snoopy [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Steeler [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Toata\ dragostea\ mea\ pentru\ diavola [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} URI::Fetch [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} urllib [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} User-Agent [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Web\ Sucker [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} webalta [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} WebCollage [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Wells\ Search\ II [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} WEP\ Search [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWW-Mechanize [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} zermelo [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus\.*Webster [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ZyBorg [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
# Abuse bot blocking rule end
order allow,deny
allow from all
# Start Custom Blocks
# Bluecoat
deny from 8.21.4.254
deny from 65.46.48.192/30
deny from 65.160.238.176/28
deny from 85.92.222.0/24
deny from 206.51.36.0/22
deny from 216.52.23.0/24
# cyveillance (already blocked 38.*)
deny from 38.100.19.8/29
deny from 38.100.21.0/24
deny from 38.100.41.64/26
deny from 38.105.71.0/25
deny from 38.105.83.0/27
deny from 38.112.21.140/30
deny from 38.118.42.32/29
deny from 65.213.208.128/27
deny from 65.222.176.96/27
deny from 65.222.185.72/29
# Cyberpatrol
deny from 38.103.17.160/27
# Internet Identity - Anti-Phishing
deny from 66.113.96.0/20
deny from 70.35.113.192/27
# Ironport
deny from 204.15.80.0/22
# Lightspeed Systems Security
deny from 66.17.15.128/26
deny from 69.84.207.32/27
deny from 69.84.207.128/25
# Layered Technologies
deny from 72.36.128.0/17
deny from 72.232.0.0/16
deny from 72.233.0.0/17
deny from 216.32.0.0/14
# M86
deny from 67.192.231.224/29
deny from 208.90.236.0/22
# McAfee-Secure-Computing
deny from 69.48.241.64/26
deny from 80.66.0.0/19
deny from 192.55.214.0/24
deny from 207.67.117.0/24
# Phish-Inspector.com
deny from 209.147.127.208/28
# Prescient Software, Inc. Phishmongers
deny from 198.186.190.0/23
deny from 198.186.192.0/23
deny from 198.186.194.0/24
# urlfilterdb
deny from 207.210.99.32/29
# websense-in.car1.sandiego1.level3.net
deny from 4.53.120.22
# Websense
deny from 66.194.6.0/24
deny from 67.117.201.128/28
deny from 69.67.32.0/20
deny from 131.191.87.0/24
deny from 204.15.64.0/21
deny from 208.80.192.0/21
deny from 212.62.26.64/27
deny from 213.168.226.0/24
deny from 213.168.241.0/30
deny from 213.168.242.0/30
deny from 213.236.150.16/28
# Yandex
deny from 77.88.0.0/18
deny from 77.88.22.0/23
deny from 77.88.24.0/21
deny from 77.88.24.0/22
deny from 77.88.28.0/22
deny from 77.88.36.0/23
deny from 77.88.42.0/23
deny from 77.88.44.0/24
deny from 77.88.50.0/23
deny from 87.250.224.0/19
deny from 87.250.230.0/23
deny from 87.250.252.0/22
deny from 93.158.128.0/18
deny from 93.158.137.0/24
deny from 93.158.144.0/21
deny from 93.158.144.0/23
deny from 93.158.146.0/23
deny from 93.158.148.0/22
deny from 95.108.128.0/17
deny from 95.108.128.0/24
deny from 95.108.152.0/22
deny from 95.108.216.0/23
deny from 95.108.240.0/21
deny from 95.108.248.0/23
deny from 178.154.128.0/17
deny from 178.154.160.0/22
deny from 178.154.164.0/23
deny from 199.36.240.0/22
deny from 213.180.192.0/19
deny from 213.180.204.0/24
deny from 213.180.206.0/23
deny from 213.180.209.0/24
deny from 213.180.218.0/23
deny from 213.180.220.0/23
# End HackRepair.com Blacklist
# END Better WP Security

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://[w.]*([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/%1 !^[w.]*([^/]+)/\1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag\= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*|=$).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(&#x22;|&#x27;|&#x3C;|&#x3E;|&#x5C;|&#x7B;|&#x7C;).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F|127\.0).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|select|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you help me spot where the problem is?

EDIT - it appears that adding "index" to the url fixes the issue, but it's the only server which is giving me problems. So basically this works http://siliconbeachla.com/index?ai1ec_render_css=1358419759&ver=3.5

Answer (score 1):

I'm still looking to see the error, but you can probably find it yourself faster by turning on the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).

```
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
```

This logs which rules were compared and applied to a request, which makes debugging this a lot easier than staring at complex rewrite rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This was capturing the request for the CSS and redirecting to index.php - which mysteriously was giving a 403 error, as well as serving the page content. It looks like you're modifying this already as the behaviour on the server is changing.

btw I'd recommend not having an empty path for the dynamic CSS. Instead of this:

```
?ai1ec_render_css=1358530067&ver=3.5
```

have:

```
ai1ec_render.css?somevar=1358530067&ver=3.5
```

It will make it much easier to write the rewrite rules, and be more obvious for anyone else trying to following the rewriting.

Comment: The first url is showing the index but if you look at the calendar page you'll see that there is a 403. i guess that when you click on it you get the index because whatever 403 would show you the index

Comment: That's really weird even 'http://siliconbeachla.com/' is returning a 403 - but it's also returning the page content. So somewhere else there must be something somewhere that is intercepting all requests with an empty path, and serving the homepage with a 403 error.

Comment: I've posted the full .htaccess file